# Cisco 871w security

Tags: networking, cisco, ios

I purchased a 871W ISR for a small business and want to know what's best use practice when setting up security for this type of router.

At the present time I have a static IP assigned to it and can SSH into it from the outside.  Is this safe? If not should I setup VPN to access it from the outside? Is there a VPN how-to (or a link) where I can learn how to set it up.

I was also thinking about blocking icmp from the outside. Is this even necessary if I setup a VPN?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have personally always opted to set up the ACL so that ssh is only allowed from certain source IPs.  Although if you don't have a static IP from where you are the administrator that is not really an option.  I would say there is not anything particularly wrong with opening ssh but you probably want a strong password.  Also, it doesn't hurt to run ssh on a non-standard port.

As far as VPN, one of the main reasons it exists is to open it from the outside.  For people to "VPN-IN" from home the keyword you want to look for when it comes to Cisco is "Client Initiated VPN".  I think you probably need the security feature set for that if I am not mistaken.  This is more money under the new licensing model.  This last bit about the licensing might be misinformation though...